# HTML: How do I make an image to be above everything in a webpage

Tags: html

In [this](http://jamkay-travels.tumblr.com/) page, I want the "where we've been" to be above everything and fixed to that position on the page so that if you scroll you don't see it.

I'm a noob and the code's a mess I know, but any quick fixes? Line 126 is where the picture is coded.

Thanks

Comment: post the code? please

Comment: you want the position to be fixed? Then, obviously, use `position:fixed`

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS

```
<div style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;">
     <img src="img.jpg" style="position: absolute; top: 30px; left: 70px;"/>
</div>
```

The "TOP" will make the image be ontop of everything. And you can also set your position by changing the top: 30 and left: 70.